# wordpress gutenberg url popover custom options

Tags: block-editor

so basically i want a link only to be clickable/ active on mobile viewport. I have the css working, but its just implementing it now. So i think there are 2 options for this:

option 1:
The way i see it is I could make a new a new button on the editor-format-toolbar with the same functionality as the insert link button but in the custom button it has a class to it.

option 2:
or the other way could be to add another toggle option to be able to add a class to the current url popover. I have seen this done in some plugins. I'm just not sure how to go about this.

any advice would be helpful.

also heres an image to better explain.

[image]